# Arduino Leonardo turkish keyboard support

Tags: layout, arduino, keyboard, turkish

I want to write an keyboard automation but when I execute it, some problems exists because of keyboard layout. And also I found a repo for this but I really don't know how to import this library (tried download zip and include lib from zip file but got `Error: 13 INTERNAL: Library install failed: moving extracted archive to destination dir: library not valid` error)

Repo: https://github.com/berkayyildi/Ardunio-Leonardo-Turkish-Layout-Keyboard

This is the chars which has problem

```
- *
i ı
" İ
$ +
= -
' i
; ş
( )
+ _
) =
{ Ğ
/ .
. ç
} Ü
: Ş
\ ,
, ö
```

For explaining, I want to write . char but arduino writes ç, I'm writing - char but arduino writes *

Like this:

Command: `Keyboard.print(F("-This is a text ...-"))`

Output: `*Thıs ıs a text ççç*`

Btw my keyboard is turkish-q layout

Comment: is there any way to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Keyboard/blob/master/src/KeyboardLayout.h